# Post to Facebook Page as Page from Website Backend

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want users of my site to be able to share (publish) content to our company Page feed, and have it appear as though the posts were made by the Page itself.

The problem is, I don't want individual users to have to login with their own Facebook accounts. I want the App to publish to the page on their behalf.

I thought by acquiring an Access Token via a server-side request using my App ID and App Secret I could have the App authenticated to post.

Facebook's App dashboard won't let me add the publish_pages and manage_pages permissions for the app without a Review, and the guidelines state that there must be a Facebook Login.

Am I going about this wrong?

UPDATE

As the documentation shows, I acquired the Page Access Token by viewing a list of the pages I manage and grabbing the Access Token from there.

However, I always get the following error:

> Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API
>   argument

I've got the correct App ID and App Secret from my App, and the right Page Access Token from my /me/accounts list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is something that the folks at Facebook had in mind for something that would conceivably be an option; it's not terribly safe. To have anyone on the Web to be able to post to Facebook as someone they're not is extremely dangerous; it could be construed as the official voice of the company, or at least give users the ability to say some really nasty things while masquerading as the company's official voice.

Comment: Get a User access token. Extend it to a long lived access token. Call /me/accounts to get the page access token. Now the page access token will never expire so just put it in your code or database and use it from there on

Comment: @WizKid If I use the User Access Token to acquire the Page Access Token, can I still post to the Page as though I were the Page and not the User?

Comment: To use a user access token to acquire the page access token is the only way you can get a page access token.

Comment: Are you sending the appsecret_proof in your request? (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests)

Comment: @BjörnKaiser How do I use the appsecret_proof with PHP SDK v5? There aren't any parameters defined for that in the documentation...

Comment: hi @HWD, finaly, how did you managed this ? Because I'm exactly in same scenario ... everything works well as admin, but since I use standard user, I can't get the token ...